# Add a repertory res/layout-large

Tags: android, layout

How Can I add the repertory res/layout-large with Eclipse ?

I don't find the way so if someone have the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You just create a folder called `layout-large/` inside the resources folder.

I think it's `File > New > Folder`

You could also just copy and paste the existing layout folder and insert the new name when the Eclipse dialog pops up.

Normally, eclipse automatically generates it for you when you first create the project. Perhaps, you've initially created your project at an older api level.

Comment: It's works ! And yes eclipse automatically generates my xml file ! :)

Comment: I've a little question : I've a xml file for the folder layout-small. And the same file for the layout-large. But for the phones with a large screen,the display is very bad so do I have to change the dimension file in layout-normal, layout-large ..

Comment: What I originally meant was that Eclipse normally creates it for you when you first create a new project. In your case however, when you've just copied and pasted the layout folder and renamed that copy to layout-large/ it will copy the previous xml file as well (which will need to be modified).

Comment: By the way, are you sure your phone has a large screen? And not just a very high density? I believe large screens are usually the new tablets, not phones (thought, I could be wrong).

Comment: What is the model name of the large screen device you're testing on?

Comment: So If I understand, the xml file for every layout (small, large) need to modifie for to have the good display, I'm good ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27580/discussion-between-stephan-branczyk-and-user1086267)

Comment: For the nexus 7, you'll want to read this more specifically: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html